# systemd-journald log location

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, systemd-journald

I am asking what may be a simple question before diving into the source code to see if the answer is out there: Is the `/var/log/journal` location for systemd journal files hard-coded into the binaries? By that, I do not mean "is it the default?" I mean that I have attempted to override the default in every location I could find which might control the setting, and `systemd-journald` merrily ignores those settings and goes back to the `/var/log/journal` location. Or stop logging altogether. These locations include:

```
/etc/systemd/journald.conf
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf
/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journal-flush.service
```

Am I missing a configuration setting somewhere? The distro is Ubuntu 16.04. System design constraints prompt the question, so please, no "Why in world would you ever..." type answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s hard-coded. `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf` sets up the directory (via the `systemd-tmpfiles` service), but journald doesn’t check there to see what the directory should be. Also, you shouldn’t edit files in `/usr/lib/` anyways – all systemd services support an override mechanism that doesn’t require editing files which belong to the package manager (e. g. `/etc/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf` can be used to completely override `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf`).